# Is there a list of all the EOS cameras using the T3 vertical release?

Tags: canon, remote, triggers

I've tried to find a complete list of all the EOS cameras using the T3 vertical release for remote shutter release. The only info I got was that EOS 3 was the first camera to use the N3 connector. This does not differ between the cameras that had no remote trigger socket and an actual T3 one (and possible other connectors). Is there a list of all the EOS cameras using the T3 vertical release?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you were referring to the Rebel T3 camera that uses an E3 remote connection. Any camera that uses the T3 connector is long out of production and so is the T3 shutter release adapter that was only available through Canon Professional services.

Comment: See http://bobatkins.com/photography/eosfaq/eosfaq24/9miscellany.html#q24

Comment: Note that the material at that link was current as of 1993.

Comment: And the T3 vertical release, as it was officially called, was already rare in 2000.   http://photo.net/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0017jd

Comment: No problem, I was not clear. I will correct it. If it was rare in 2000 and EOS 3 was the first one using the N3 the transistion must have been quite immediate assuming there where no other connector in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were several early EOS cameras that used the T3 connector for both wired remotes and to connect a vertical shutter release. Many of those early models are listed at [this link that was current as of 1993](http://bobatkins.com/photography/eosfaq/eosfaq24/9miscellany.html#q24). ***"compatible with T50, T70, T80 & T90 cameras as well as the EOS-1, EOS 5/A2E/A2, and the EOS 620/30/50/RT series when those cameras are fitted with optional grip GR-20"***

The vertical release was only available directly from Canon Professional Services and was not distributed via the Canon dealer network. By the year 2000 the [T3 vertical release](http://photo.net/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0017jd) was a rare, hard to find item.

You can still find [adapters](http://www.adorama.com/CARSAT3.html) that allow using standard cable releases with 2.5mm stereo mini plugs (what Canon calls the E3) with cameras with a [T3 socket](http://www.digiwowo.com/canon-cable-release-adapter-t3.html).

Mike Sowsun photos added
[image]
[image]
[image]